# Two HTML table under each other

Tags: html, html-table, alignment

So I have two html table under each other
Each table has two columns
The problem that I want each column in the below table to be exactly under the similar column from the above column

|Table 1|
|----|-----| 
|----|-----|

|Table 2|
|----|-----|
|----|-----|

Edited:

I tried to use

```
<td valign="top"></td>
```

However I do not think that this the proper code

Comment: try setting the width of the `<td>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, use same td class for both tables.

## HTML Sample

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr><td class="first">aaa</td><td class="second">aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">aaa</td><td class="second">aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">aaa</td><td class="second">aaa</td></tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
<table id="table2">
    <tr><td class="first">aaa</td><td class="second">aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">aaa</td><td class="second">aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">aaa</td><td class="second">aaa</td></tr>
</table>
```

## CSS

```
#table1, #table2 {float:left;width:700px;}

td.first{ width:40%;}

td.second{ width:60%;}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add a class to the tables you should be able to remove the margins and padding

```
table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
```

If you need them to line up precisely then specify the width of each field

```
td {
    width: 10%; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the same widths for the columns of the tables.

However, the widths you set are basically just suggestions and may be overridden by browsers due to content requirements. Using `table-layout: fixed` in CSS on both tables usually fixes this, but it may have nasty side effects (e.g., content that does not it is just truncated). And in any case, you would have to make some guess on the column widths, instead of letting browsers calculate them dynamically.

The best approach is probably to combine the two tables into one table.

Answer (score -1):

Try the example given by "yeyene..

elese you can do the following;
Use CSS tables.. then this issue can be sorted out easily.

[csstables](http://www.textfixer.com/resources/css-tables.php)